# jQuery: Toggle title attribute of href depending on state

Tags: jquery

I need to accomplish something quite simple, and what I have so far only works half way.

I have a link `<a href="#" class="favorites">Favorite</a>` as you can see it has no *title* attribute.

When page is loaded a script adds this *title* attribute:

`<a href="#" class="favorites" title="Add to Favorites">Favorites</a>`

When clicked, a class *checked* is toggled and then the *title* attribute should be changed, so the end result would be like this:

`<a href="#" class="favorites checked" title="Item added to Favorites">Favorites</a>`

I have this code but although it changes the title attribute for the new one, when clicked again the title attribute isn't swapped, which what I need:

```
$('.favorites').attr('title','Add to Favorites').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('checked').attr('title','Added to Favorites');
});
```

Any ides how I can 'toggle' attributes on click?

I created this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/DPVZx/1/) to show this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.favorites').attr('title', 'Add to Favorites').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    var title = 'Add to Favorites' ;

    if( $(this).hasClass('checked')){
       title = 'Added to Favorites';
    }
    $(this).attr('title', title);
});​
```

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/DPVZx/2/)

Comment: Sushanth --, your answer and **wirey's** work great, but I selected yours because you posted first... by 1 second :p. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do inside an is/else or just use ternary operator

```
//Toggle attribute
$('.favorites').attr('title', 'Add to Favorites').click(function() {
     $(this)
        .toggleClass('checked')
        .attr('title', $(this).hasClass('checked') ? "Item added to Favorites":'Added to Favorites');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WwqYC/

which is eventually the same as

```
$('.favorites').attr('title', 'Add to Favorites').click(function() {        
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');        
    if($(this).hasClass('checked')){
        $(this).attr('title',"Item added to Favorites");
    }else{
        $(this).attr('title','Added to Favorites');
    } 
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `data-` attribute to store the alternate title, then switch that with the `title` attribute each click. jQuery will automatically retrieve whatever's in a `data-` attribute using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method. This has the advantage of being very flexible -- any `.favorites` link can swap any title text using this one event handler.

```
<a href="#" class="favorites" data-title2="Added to Favorites" title="Add to Favorites">Favorites</a>​
```

JS:

```
$('.favorites').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        t1 = $this.attr('title'),
        t2 = $this.data('title2');
 $this.toggleClass('checked').attr('title',t2).data('title2',t1);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Na2pE/

Or, if you want it to be even more flexible, add some code to detect the existence of `data-title2` first:

```
$('.favorites').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        t1 = $this.attr('title'),
        t2 = $this.data('title2');
    $this.toggleClass('checked');
    if (t2) {
        $this.attr('title', t2).data('title2', t1);
    };
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, but I'd written a little plugin to handle the *toggling of properties*

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function(options){
            var defaults = {
                propName: '',
                toggleTo: '',
                toggleFrom: ''
            }

            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

                if($this.data('toggled') == 'false' || !$this.data('toggled')){
                    $this.data('toggled', 'true');
                    $this.prop(settings.propName, settings.toggleTo);
                }else{
                    $this.data('toggled', 'false');
                    $this.prop(settings.propName, settings.toggleFrom);                                              
                }
           });
        }
    } 
    $.fn.toggleProperty = function( method ) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.toggleProperty' );
        }           
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Just place this within an event call and you're good.

```
$('element').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleProperty({
        propName: 'title',
        toggleTo: 'Added From Favorites',
        toggleFrom: $(this).prop('title') 
    });
});
```

Additionally the `toggleFrom` property allows you to pass in the initial title, or a new title you want to toggle back and forth between.

Comment: Ohgodwhy, thanks for the info, very valuable. Will consider it next time I need to deal with attributes toggling. Gave you a vote. Thanks.